# android save content on setContentView()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I created an activity in which I created two classes so that on click of `radiobutton` I'm setting the content using `setContentView()`.

But my problem is when I try to switch between the two layouts, the **content of one layout is destroyed**.

I have also tried making two activities for two layouts and use Intent to call another activity.

Can anyone suggest me a method to switch between layouts with saving the contents?
I also tried using `android:saveenabled="true"` for the particular widget.

Comment: Your question is wrong! You are asking "how to fix your solution" instead "what is your initial problem". And your solution is bad from the beginning. Describe what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the two layouts within a `ViewSwitcher` and then switching between them by using `showNext()` to toggle which layout is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one activity with a ViewFlipper in your layout. For Example:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
    <include android:id="@+id/include1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/layout1"/>
    <include android:id="@+id/include2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/layout2"/>

</ViewFlipper>
```

Then, in your activity code you should have something like this:

```
ViewFlipper flip = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
flip.showNext();
flip.showPrevious();
```